# @Transactional and @Lock - what to change?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions, locking

I have Service which is annotated with @Transactional annotation. And repository method with Lock.

Once I had **DataIntegrityViolationException** (the entity already exists in repository) when one thread was trying to update repository with new entity using default CRUDRepository save() method. It failed in the getNumber() method.

Any assumptions why that could happen? And what should I change with the annotations maybe?

```
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class MyService {
private ComplexNumber getNumber(ComplexKey key, boolean updateInCache) {
        Optional<ENumber> documentNumber;

        if (updateInCache) {
            documentNumber = numberRepository.findOneForUpdate(key.getClientId(), key.getDocumentType(), key.getResetDate());
        } else {
            documentNumber = numberRepository.get(key);
        }

        ComplexNumber complexNumber = new ComplexNumber();
        if (documentNumber.isEmpty()) {
            numberRepository.put(key, complexNumber);
        } else {
            complexNumber.setPrefix(documentNumber.get().getPrefix());
            complexNumber.setNumber(documentNumber.get().getNumber());
        }

        complexNumber.setNumber(complexNumber.getNumber() + 1);

        if (updateInCache) {
            numberRepository.put(key, complexNumber);
        }

        return complexNumber;
    }
}


public interface EDocumentNumberRepository extends JpaRepository<ENumber, ComplexKey> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("select e from ENumber e where e.clientId = :clientId ")
    Optional<ENumber> findOneForUpdate(@Param("clientId") Long clientId);

    default Optional<ENumber> get(ComplexKey key) {
            return findById(key);
        }

    default void put(ComplexKey key, ComplexNumber complexNumber) {
        ENumber number = new ENumber()
            .setKey(key)
            .setPrefix(complexNumber.getPrefix())
            .setNumber(complexNumber.getNumber());
        save(number);
}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that somehow, the entity did not exist and you have passed `updateInCache=true`? Because in such a case, you would try to save the entity twice.

Comment: @AidHadzic Even if it already existed, the entity would be saved once with the new ComplexNumber(). And with a different value for the second time (complexNumber + 1).

Comment: Hey @EvgeniaRubanova was my answer helpful to your issue? If so I would appreciate if you marked it as correct!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enforce the locking to happen as soon as you start using the repository inside the `@Transactional` method. Currently only `findOneForUpdate` method locks the table.

To do that you need to annotate with `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` all the repository methods you need to use inside your service method. Read more about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jpa-transaction-locks#enable_transaction_locks).